# Laravel custom validation rule on valid email

Tags: php, validation, email, laravel-5

So basically I have a simple form and one of the fields is an email.

My controller responsible for this form is the following(showing only the essentials)

```
$messages = array(
    'rsvp_email.required' => 'A valid email is required.')
);

$rules = array(
    'rsvp_email' => 'required|max:150|email',
);        

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$messages);
```

Now there are 2 scenarios:

a) The email is not inserted and the above validation works with the custom message(This works OK)

b) The email is not in a valid format (myemail@email) and the resulted error message is `The rsvp email must be a valid email address.` which is not what I want to be displayed.

What additional rule should I include for a valid email?

Thank

Comment: when you enter myemail@email this return "The rsvp email must be a valid email address"? what do you want to show?

Comment: I want a custom message, for example "A valid email is required (myname@email.com)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to change this message go to the following path:

resources/lang/en/validation.php

and change value of email index.

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about the default messages in this folder! Cheers!

Comment: You are Welcome